Setting HTTP header field has no effect
I'm doing a MitM attack homework. It requires me to change the HTTP payload (adding script tags to the HTML content). I was able to inject the script but I found the content received on the user's side is always cut short. I then realized that the Content-Length field in the HTTP header wasn't increased to accommodate the longer HTTP data.
I tried to set the Content-Length header this way. new_packet.show() prints fine, showing the updated Content-Length. But when I checked on the client side it still sees the original Content-Length as if nothing was changed.
res: HTTPResponse = tcp[HTTPResponse]
res.fields["Content_Length"] = content_len
new_packet = IP(src=ip.src, dst=ip.dst) / tcp
new_packet.show()
send(new_packet)

I checked other related answers here and on scapy's github issues page but the discussions seem to be very outdated. Has anyone successfully changed the header fields this way? Am I supposed to use another method to modify header fields?

Please, make the question a [mcve]

I just wanted to know whether http_packet.fields["Some-Header"] = my_value is the correct and intended way of modifying HTTP header fields in scapy and if anyone has changed it this way.

Well, show() is definitely not the right way to send the modified packet.

Edited the snippet to make it more clear

Ended up directly modifying TCP's Raw layer. It seems that scapy would try to parse the header fields into an HTTPResponse object if you access it though res = packet[HTTPResponse] and leave only the HTTP body in the Raw layer load. And it also seems that if I modify the parsed header fields directly (e.g. res.fields["Content_Length"] = "123"), it's not effective. But if I modify the unparsed TCP Raw layer directly, it works. Here is what I did to inject a script tag and also modify the "Content-Length" HTTP header:
old_load: str = tcp[Raw].load.decode()

[old_headers, old_body] = old_load.split("\r\n\r\n")

new_body = old_body.split("</body>")
new_body.insert(-1, f"<script>{script}</script>")
new_body = "".join(new_body)
new_headers: str = old_headers.replace(f"Content-Length: {len(old_body)}", f"Content-Length: {len(new_body)}")

new_load = "\r\n\r\n".join([new_headers, new_body])
tcp[Raw].load = new_load


You could have done
res.Content_Length = None

To have Scapy recalculate it for you automatically.
